# Grep for matches inside a while loop

Tags: bash, loops, grep

I have a file that contains server names and the number of cpu cores that I extracted from Ansible. I'd like to clean up the appearance of the file by just listing the server_name and the # of cores.

```
while read line; do

  server_name=`grep -q "SUCCESS" $line | awk '{print $1}'`

  cores=`grep -q "ansible_processor_cores" $line | awk '{print $2}'`

  printf "$server_name has $cores cores\n"

done <ansible_file
```

When I use `grep "SUCCESS" ansible_file | awk '{print $1}'` on the cmd line, I get exactly what I am looking for. However, I need to pull both vars out of the file. This is why I am trying to read the file line-by-line.

When run as a script, grep is complaining about "No such file or directory". What am I missing here?

The format of the ansible_file is:

```
server_name | SUCCESS => {

         "ansible_facts": {
             "ansible_processor_cores": 8
         },
         "changed": false

    }
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
grep <server_name>: No such file or directory

grep |: No such file or directory

grep SUCCESS: No such file or directory

grep =>: No such file or directory
```

etc

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in your question. Please do add samples of input and sample of expected output in your question too with code tags and let us know then.

Comment: `-q` option supresses output, are you sure you want it?

Comment: `grep "SUCCESS" ansible_file` works because `ansible_file` is a filename. `$line` is _not_ a filename. Hence "No such file or directory."

Comment: @RuudHelderman It is my understanding that grep works on other input than just files. Isn't $line like STDIN?

Comment: @Rodney `grep` works on files and streams. `$line` is neither; it's a string. To turn a string into a stream, either use `echo` or use a 'here string'.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Ah, I see that now. Thanks, that helps. I added echo $line | to cmds feeding the server_name var, but that didn't work either.

Comment: pluse-uno for sample data and code! In the future, also include your exact output requirements based on your sample input. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Spawning way too many unnecessary processes here.

in `awk` -

```
awk '/SUCCESS/ { svr=$1; } /ansible_processor_cores/ { if(svr){ printf "%s has %s cores\n", svr, $2; } } /\} *$/ { svr=""; }' ansible_file
```

in `perl` -

```
perl -ne '/^(\S+).*SUCCESS/ and $msg="$1 has"; /"ansible_processor_cores": (\d+)/ and $msg and print "$msg $1 cores\n"; /} *$/ and $msg="";' ansible_file
```

In `sed` -

```
sed -En '/SUCCESS/,/^ *} *$/ {
  /SUCCESS/{ s/ .*//; h; }
  /ansible_processor_cores/{ s/.*ansible_processor_cores"*: ([0-9]+).*/\1/; H; }
  /^ *} *$/{ x; s/^(.+)(\n)([0-8]+)$/\1 has \3 cores/; p; x; d; }
}' ansible_file
```

pure `bash` -

```
server_name=''; cores='';
while read line; do
  if [[ "${line%% *}" =~ }$ ]]
  then server_name=''; cores='';
  fi
  [[ "$line" =~ SUCCESS ]] && server_name="${line%% *}"
  [[ "$line" =~ ansible_processor_cores ]] && cores="${line##* }"
  if [[ -n "$server_name" && -n "$cores" ]]
  then printf "$server_name has $cores cores\n"
       server_name=''; cores='';
  fi
done < ansible_file
```

(Also, the `-q` argument to `grep` is for *quiet*, meaning "don't output anything".)

Try those.

Comment: This should output only one line after data is gathered. If your playbook is accessing multiple servers at a time this won't work as I understood it...or is all the info on every line when it *does* match?

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting a syntax error near unexpected token `"${line[*]}"`.

Also, the closing paren without an opening paren confuses me.

Comment: Yes, this is actually just an adhoc cmd, but it is accessing many servers.

Comment: The second example above worked, but only read the first line from the file. It did not interate through the rest of the file.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I moved the printf statement to be inside the while loop.

Comment: If these don't match the actual formatting, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` returns the whole line from a match. Consequently what you're asking it to do is to return $line if there's a match. From your description, there always will be a match.

To extract the values server_name and core from $line with minimal changes to your code:

```
while read line; do

  if [[ $line =~ SUCCESS ]]; then
    server_name=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
  fi;
  if [[ $line =~ ansible_processor_cores ]]; then
    cores=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
  fi;

  printf "$server_name has $cores cores\n"

done <ansible_file
```

Comment: Yes, I am only interested in the lines that match, but not every line will match. Only the 1st and 3rd lines contain the information I am after.

Comment: Sorry - I responded too quickly. I've edited to something which I think will do the trick!

Comment: I was able to get part of this work, but not all of it. The $server_name var was correctly assigned, but not the $cores var. I have not been able to get awk to work like it did with $server_name. I don't understand why, though.

Comment: I have tested it all again based on your input. If you do this `echo "\"ansible_processor_cores\": 8" | awk '{print $2}'` you'll see that it returns `8`, so perhaps your input is different?

Comment: I just moved the final printf outside the loop. It doesn't belong there.

Comment: Moving the printf outside to loop will not capture every server and the number of cpu cores it contains. It would only capture that last value assigned once the loop has completed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use a while loop. If each file you're parsing has a single server entry, just remove the while loop.

Otherwise, if a file can have two or more entries, I think I would grep with a multiline regex parts of the file.

```
$ perl -0pe 's/([0-9a-zA-Z_]*).*SUCCESS(?:(?!ansible_processor_cores)(.|\n))*ansible_processor_cores[^\d]*(\d*)(?:(?!\}\n)(.|\n))*}/Server \1 has \3 cores/g; s/.*(FAIL|ERROR)(?:(?!}\n)(\n|.))*}\n//;' data1.txt
```

It produces:

```
Server server_name has 8 cores
Server server_name has 8 cores
```

From data:

```
server_name | SUCCESS => {

 "ansible_facts": {
     "ansible_processor_cores": 8
 },
 "changed": false

}
server_name | FAIL => {

 "ansible_facts": {
     "ansible_processor_cores": 99
 },
 "changed": false

}
server_name | SUCCESS => {

 "ansible_facts": {
     "ansible_processor_cores": 8
 },
 "changed": false

}
```

**Explained:** 
I use two regexs, one to change matching data and one to remove unmatching data.

Matching: `s/([0-9a-zA-Z_]*).*SUCCESS(?:(?!ansible_processor_cores)(.|\n))*ansible_processor_cores[^\d]*(\d*)(?:(?!\}\n)(.|\n))*}/Server \1 has \3 cores/g;` 
Not matching: `s/.*(FAIL|ERROR)(?:(?!}\n)(\n|.))*}\n//;`

**Matching** 
`([0-9a-zA-Z_]*)` is the server name, but is only included if it's proceeded by `SUCCESS`. It than searches for the first "ansible_processor_cores" hit with `(?:(?!ansible_processor_cores)(.|\n))*ansible_processor_cores`. It groups an N amount of numbers after the cores and proceeds to include everything until a single `}` is found on a line (which is closing the "ansible server node").

**Not matching** 
Takes everything matching `FAIL` or `ERROR` and finds the closing character `}`. If found it replaces it with nothing.

Comment: I apologize if I didn't communicate this clearly, but I am trying to parse a single file that contains 4200 lines.

Comment: This will work regardless of the amount of lines I think. But if 1 file has 1 server/node/whatever it's better to use grep once or twice because it's better to read.

Comment: Don't pipe a `perl` solution through an external `grep`. Add a test to control whether it prints.

Comment: Didn't had the time to fix it entirely. Will fix it Monday :-)

Answer (score -1):

I apologize for the delay in responding. I took some time to deepen my knowledge and experience with sed. I was ultimately able to use sed to get what I needed.

Thank you to everyone that helped increase my bash knowledge. I learned something from each of you.